# How do I dual boot backtrack 5 r3 and Windows 8?

Tags: dual-boot, backtrack

I have already successfully completed the Ubuntu and windows 8 dual boot but now I am trying to add backtrack and my computer (Hp 2000 Notebook pc) will not even see my backtrack files.

I am trying to install backtrack from a usb and I have already "Extracted"(yes I know) the iso file.

Comment: Look into Kali-Linux instead of Backtrack, as it's the Backtrack replacement and there won't be any new Backtrack releases

Answer (score 0):

Did you write the iso to the usb? If not use http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/ or some similar software. Then just restart your computer, make sure that you can boot from the usb and play around with backtrack without installing first.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a bootable usb with backtrack inside you can use Universal USB Installer, http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/. I use UUI to install linux distro on USB. Its a portable software no installation needed. UUI work perfect to make bootable linux and windows. The software size is just 1 MB.

Using UUI you doesn't need to extract the iso file.